# Localize html attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net

I can easily localize any inline text by using

```
<asp:Localize runat="server" meta:resourcekey="LocalizeResource5" Text="Actions"></asp:Localize>
```

Is it possible to localize Html attributes directly in aspx code, without using code-behind or other “tricks”? (I mean: supported by Visual studio Resource files generator)
Example:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="text to localize" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After my experience with localizing quite few websites, I can tell you that ASP.NET localization system is pretty *bad* (would use some other word here... but must resist the temptation).

You've ran into one problem... for me the bigger problem was changing localized text without forcing user to reload the page.

So, what I would advise you is to ditch ASP.NET localization and switch to something way better, namely [Angular-Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/).

Unlike ASP.NET localization system, [Angular-Translate](http://angular-translate.github.io/) has seen WAY much more usage in production and most of the problems you'll run into have already been solved in the library. Plus, you can use it pretty quickly, without much AngularJs knowledge - just see getting started example.